# How to implement x:y named delegate methods?

Tags: macos, cocoa, delphi, webview, delegates

I'd like to create a WebView's WebFrameLoadDelegate's method in Delphi for this obj-c method:

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender didFinishLoadForFrame:(WebFrame *)frame
```

How should this method be declared in delphi?

These don't work:

```
public
    procedure didFinishLoadForm( webView:WebView; Sender:WebFrame ); cdecl;
    procedure webViewdidFinishLoadForm( webView:WebView; Sender:WebFrame ); cdecl;
```

Setting the delegate class seems to be OK using
   webview.setFrameLoadDelegate( d.GetObjectID );

Where d is TMyWebViewDelegate( TOCObject ) class, with GetObjectiveClass overridden, returning an interface(NSObject), like for the toolbar delegate here http://delphihaven.wordpress.com/2012/07/15/using-the-cocoa-toolbar-nstoolbar-in-xe2/

But my method is not called.
What's the pattern for declaring such obj-c methods?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually it is best to use the exact names of the methods and parameters (as answered by Rudy). But sometimes this is not possible. Two functions might need to have the same name, but have identical parameter types so that `overload` cannot be used. In that case you can use the `MethodName` attribute. So here's another valid solution:

```
[MethodName('webView:didFinishLoadForFrame:')]
procedure webViewdidFinishLoadForm( Sender:WebView; Frame:WebFrame ); cdecl;
```

Comment: Thank you, wow, magic hidden feature :) Are there more such undocumented features? I could not find anything about [MethodName] for example. It's not present in Emb's own source code too - in xe5 at least.

Comment: MethodName is used 4 times in the XE5 sources for iOS. So there is a chance to discover it :)

Comment: I know this is old, but this solved an issue for me in 2018. It is bizarre that this is not officially documented anywhere. Searching for "methodname" on the Delphi docwiki turns up a lot of unrelated stuff but not this.

Answer (score 3):

The correct syntax to implement the routine would be:

```
procedure webView(sender: WebView; didFinishLoadForFrame: WebFrame);
```

The name of the Objective-C selector is `webView:didFinishLoadForFrame:`. The first part must become the *exact* name of the method, the following parts must become the *exact* names of the parameters (case sensitive, because Objective-C is case sensitive). That is how Delphi maps method names to selectors.